# Integral from Feynman & Hibbs Appendix - solvable with Cauchy principal value

Tags: integration

In Appendix "Some Useful Definite Integrals" of Feynman & Hibbs "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals" they use some integral formulas that I'm struggling to derive. The integral is:

[image]

I've seen a question to solve an [almost similar integral](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742718/an-integral-from-feynman-hibbs), but the guy just gave a hint, and I still can't solve it. I know that is possible to get the solution of the "almost similar integral" just taking the partial derivative of my equation with respect
to $a$. So finding the result of the other integral is easy when we know the answer of this one, but how to solve this integral? I would appreciate some help.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with physics.

Comment: Don't use images for Math (or text). Use MathJax instead.

Comment: Did you try using the hint provided in the comments to the linked question?

Comment: Help on using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  Please not that posting images of text or mathematics is strongly discouraged on Physics SE (and several other science orientated sites on SE).

Comment: @hft Yes, I tried to use the hint. I used the first substitution $ \tau = T\sin^2\theta $, but then I wasn't able to perform the substitution $ x = \tan\theta $

Comment: Use $\frac{dx}{d\theta} = 1 + \tan^2\theta = 1 + x^2$

Comment: And you can write everything in terms of $\tan\theta = x$. For example: $\frac{1}{\sin^2}=\frac{\sin^2+\cos^2}{\sin^2} = 1+\frac{1}{x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

We aim to compute $$I(p,q)=\int_{0}^1e^{ia/(1-\tau)+ib/\tau}\frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{\tau^{2p+1}(1-\tau)^{2q+1}}}$$
where $p$ and $q$ are nonegative integers. This is an improper integral if $p$ or $q$ is $>0.$
An interesting point of this calculation is the fact that $I(0,0)$ cannot be made explicit.

Felipe mentions that the appendix of Feyman and Hicks says {Quantum mechanics and path integrals' } Dover 2010 that
$$I(0,1)=\sqrt{\frac{i\pi}{b}}e^{i(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2},$$ and Felipe mentions from another source $$  I(1,1)=\sqrt{\frac{i\pi}{ab}}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})e^{i(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2}.$$
An interesting point of this calculation is the fact that $I(0,0)$ cannot be made explicit, but is liable to be transformed in a way which makes the computation of $I(p,q)$ feasible for $p$ or $q >0.$

We first transform  the problem by considering for $s,t\geq 0$
$$J_{s,t}(p,q)=\int_0^1 e^{-\frac{s^2}{1-\tau}-\frac{t^2}{\tau}}\frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{\tau^{2p+1}(1-\tau)^{2q+1}}}$$
which converges for all integers $p,q\geq 0$  if $s,t>0$, for $q=0$ if $s=0$ and $t>0$ and for $p=0$ if $t=0$ and $s>0.$
We will show later on that $$J_{s,t}(0,0)=J_{0,s+t}(0,0)=J_{s+t,0}(0,0)\ \ \ (*).$$
We introduce for $t>0$
$$f(t)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-t^2/\cos ^2\theta}d\theta=J_{0,t}(0,0)=J_{t,0}(0,0)$$ and $$f'(t)=2t\, J_{0,t}(1,0)=2t\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-t^2/\cos ^2(\theta)}\frac{d\theta}{\cos ^2\theta}$$$$=2t\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2(1+x^2)dx}=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-t^2}$$
The consequence is that
$$J_{0,t}(1,0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2t}e^{-t^2}, \ \ J_{0,t+s}(1,0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2(t+s)}e^{-(t+s)^2}\ \ (**)$$
Now $$J_{s,t}(1,0)=\int_0^1 e^{-\frac{s^2}{1-\tau}-\frac{t^2}{\tau}}\frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{\tau^{3}(1-\tau)}}=\frac{1}{2t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}J_{s,t}(0,0)\stackrel{*}{=}\frac{1}{2t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}J_{0,s+t}(0,0)$$$$\stackrel{**}{=}\frac{1}{2t}(2(s+t))J_{0,s+t}(1,0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2t}e^{-(t+s)^2}.$$ The other values of $J_{s,t}(p,q)$ for $p+q>0$ can be obtained by derivation in $s$ and $t.$
Finally, to pass from $J_{s,t}(1,0)$ to $I(1,0)$ we just use the fact that $ (s,t)\mapsto J_{s,t}(1,0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2t}e^{-(t+s)^2}$ is an analytic function and that we can take $s^2=ia$ and $t^2=ib$, with probably some delicate justification for rigor. But Felipe, you are a physicist ready to accept this.

{Proof of (*)}

The following result of [1], Prop. 2.1, is also mentioned on page 108 of [2]:

{Theorem.} Let $\Theta$ be uniform random variable on $[0,\pi/2)$ and let $s,t>0.$ Then the two random variables
$u(\Theta)=\frac{s^2}{\cos ^2\Theta}+\frac{t^2}{\sin^2 \Theta}$ and $v(\Theta)=\frac{(s+t)^2}{\cos^2\Theta}$ have the same distribution, written $u(\Theta)\sim v(\Theta).$
In other terms, for any positive function $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ we have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}f(u(\theta))d\theta=\int_0^{\pi/2}f(v(\theta))d\theta.$$In particular $f(u)=e^{-u}$ gives (*).

{Proof.} If $b>0$ and $w=a+ib$, the Cauchy distribution $c(w)$ has density $\frac{b}{\pi((x-a)^2+b^2}.$ Problem II 12 of [3] gives an elementary proof of the following:  if
$f(z)=a_0z-b_0-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{z-b_i}$ where $a_0,\ldots,a_n\geq 0$ and if $X\sim c(w)$ then $f(X)\sim c(f(w))$ ([4] contains a  more general result of this type).
It is easy to see that $X=\tan \Theta$ has the standard Cauchy distribution $c(i)$ and therefore  $Y=sX-\frac{t}{X}$ and $Z=(s+t)X$ have the same distribution $c(i(s+t)).$ As a consequence
$$\frac{s^2}{\cos ^2\Theta}+\frac{t^2}{\sin^2 \Theta}=(s+t)^2+Y^2\sim(s+t)^2+Z^2=\frac{(s+t)^2}{\cos^2\Theta}.\ \square$$

{References.}

[1] {Cambanis, S, Keener, R. and Simons, G.} (1983) 'On $\alpha$ symmetric distributions' {J. Multivariate Anal.} {33}, 213-233.

[2] {J. Misiewicz} (2014) {Simulating stable, substable and weak stable random variables} Lambert, Saarbrucken.

[3] {G. Letac} (1994) {Exercises in probability} Springer, New York.

[4] {G. Letac} (1977) 'Which functions preserve Cauchy laws?' {Proc. Amer. Math. Soc} {67} 277-286.